# What is the algorithm (if exists) for a hash function that maps multiple data to an index inside the table?

Tags: c++, hash

Consider the following:

```
class dog {
  private:
    char * name;
    int age;
};
```

Assume that I got each of the following `Dog` input:

```
obj1: Bailey, 4
obj2: Lucy, 8
obj3: Duke, 4
```

My question is, how would I insert these objects of type `Dog` into a hash table using the `hashFunction`, so that I would be able to retrieve any one of them by either entering the name **OR** the age of the dog.

For example:

```
retrieve(4); //returns obj1 and obj3
retrieve("Lucy"); //returns obj2
```

Comment: It's called a hash function. Your question is circular.

Comment: @EJP Would you be more specific?

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using std::hash which is the main one used with ISO C++

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: The OP asked something really different indeed.

Comment: As far as I could tell the OP wanted to use a hash function, so the reference I gave shows how to use it along with other components of the standard template library.

Comment: @VeganFanatic thanks for your respond, but I am looking for an algorithm for that function, not how it is called from main.

Comment: generally exclusive or is widely used for hashing